# Preserve child stdout colors when piping to process.stdout

Tags: node.js, colors, process, stdout

If I run `npm run dev`, I get colors in the terminal window from next.js.

If I wrap this command  in a `node.js` file, like so;

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');

const child = child_process.spawn('npm', ['run', 'dev'], { shell:true });

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
```

...I lose all colors in the terminal output.

Is it possible to preserve the colors using this setup? Is it possible to wrap the command In a child process in any other way, and achieve the same result as running `rpm run dev`?

Answer (score 0):

```
require("child_process").spawn('npm', ['run', 'dev'], {
    cwd: process.cwd(),
    detached: false,
    stdio: "inherit"
});
```